# AMPL file parser with C++

Tags: c++, parsing, ampl

Is there any parser available for the AMPL format using C++ ?

I'm looking for a way to parse and read the data included in files written in AMPL format, within my C++ program

Comment: Are you aware of the [.nl file and the related ASL library](http://achille.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/what/ampl/REFS/hooking2.pdf) written in C? Writing an AMPL parser seems a tremendous task.